# #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting the following error when I try to create a TABLE in SQL.

The version of phpMyAdmin I'm using it 4.2.7.1 which says it's up to date.

Can anyone help? I can't spot an error? I have looked in similar questions relating to error 1064, but no joy

```
CREATE TABLE 'categories' (
'id' SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'category' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
UNIQUE INDEX 'category_UNIQUE' ('category' ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE 'orders' (
    'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'users_id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    'transaction_id' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    'payment_status' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    'payment_amount' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    'date_created' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
    INDEX 'date_created' ('date_created' ASC),
    INDEX 'transaction_id' ('transaction_id' ASC),
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_orders_users1' FOREIGN KEY ('id')     
        REFERENCES 'users' ('id')
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    CREATE TABLE 'pages' (
        'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        'categories_id' SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        'title' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        'description' TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
        'content' LONGTEXT NULL,
        'date_created' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
        INDEX 'date_created' ('date_created' ASC),
        INDEX 'fk_pages_categories_idx' ('categories_id')
            REFERENCES 'categories' ('id')
            ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

     ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  CREATE TABLE 'pdfs' (
      'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      'title' VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
      'description' TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
      'tmp_name' CHAR(63) NOT NULL,
      'file_name' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      'size' MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      'date_created' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY ('id')
      UNIQUE INDEX 'tmp_name_UNIQUE' ('tmp_name' ASC),
      INDEX 'date_created' ('date_created' ASC)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    CREATE TABLE ('users')
    'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'type' ENUM('member','admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'member'
    'username' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    'email' VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    'pass' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    'first_name' VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
    'last_name' VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
    'date_created' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'date_expires' DATE NOT NULL,
    'date_modified' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
      UNIQUE INDEX 'username_UNIQUE' ('username' ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX 'email_UNIQUE' ('email' ASC),
        INDEX 'login' ('email' ASC, 'pass' ASC)
      ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''categories' (
    'id' SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'catego' at line 1
```

Comment: ' <> ` - That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use back-ticks ` (next to the 1 key on my keyboard) instead of ' quotes.  This works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
   `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `category` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE INDEX `category_UNIQUE` (`category` ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: or, for a happier life, ignore them altogether

Comment: indeed! It's rare you need them.

Comment: If you're the DBA, then it's safe to say you never need them!

Answer (score 2):

Remove single quote characters from field names

Answer (score 1):

Replace ' characters that surround table names and field names by `.

There are some more syntax errors that will appear then - for example there are unneeded parentheses around 'users' table.
Also when you create 'orders' table, it has a foreign key on users, but users are declared later.

Comment: facepalm - sorry guys!